# Retain image content after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, handler

I have ajax AsyncFileUpload control and a image control. when a image is selected through uploader, i show it in the image control.
I have handler for that :

```
public class Handler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.Clear();
    if (context.Request.QueryString.Count != 0)
    {
        //Get the stored image and write in the response.
        var storedImage = context.Session["STORED_IMAGE"] as byte[];
        if (storedImage != null)
        {
            Image image = GetImage(storedImage);
            if (image != null)
            {
                context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
                image.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }
        }
    }
}
private Image GetImage(byte[] storedImage)
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream(storedImage);
    return Image.FromStream(stream);
}
public bool IsReusable
{
    get
    {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

And in Aspx page  :

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Always" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div class="FakeFileUpload">
                    <div class="FakeFileUploadDiv">
                        <asp:Image ID="imgPhoto" runat="server" ImageUrl="download.jpeg" alt="Employee Photo"
                            Height="150px" Width="150px" />
                    </div>
                    <cc11:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUpload1" runat="server" ThrobberID="loader"
                        CssClass="FileUploadClass" OnClientUploadComplete="OnClientAsyncFileUploadComplete"
                        OnUploadedComplete="AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete" Width="150" />
                    <asp:Image ID="loader" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Script :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function getRandomNumber() {
            var randomnumber = Math.random(10000);
            return randomnumber;
        }
        function OnClientAsyncFileUploadComplete(sender, args) {
            var handlerPage = '<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("Handler.ashx")%>';
            var queryString = '?randomno=' + getRandomNumber();
            var src = handlerPage + queryString;
            var clientId = '<%=imgPhoto.ClientID %>';
            document.getElementById(clientId).setAttribute("src", src);
        }
    </script>
```

this all works fine, but when i click any other button, the content in the image control is lost. I want that image still be there when a post back occurs.

I got the code from :
http://www.harinadh.com/2012/07/profile-picture-using-asyncfileupload.html

Anyone can help me doing this please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code to see where it may be failing?

Comment: I did not get where it might be failing. The session["STORED_IMAGE"] shows some number(byte). I do not know how to assign that session to image control after a button click.

Comment: Handlers do not handle postbacks, I don't believe.  Check out this other SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093405/how-do-i-get-a-custom-ihttphandler-to-be-capable-of-handling-postbacks

Comment: So there is no other way to retain the image?